# Font resolution changes on resize

Tags: glyph

I have bought online the Hackney font. This is great font, but depending on the size of the displayed area, or the size of the font, this latter suddenly changes its resolution. [Here is a comparison between font resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDKPZ.png)

I don't know how to fix this, I would like at least to lower the limit and show high resolution, but is it even possible ?
Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Sorry, Brother But that is what it looks like. There is no error.

Comment: Damn'ed ! my biggest fear just got real x)

Comment: Sorry, Brother. No problem it's good overall

Comment: I have noticed on smartphone the font is properly rendered.. perhaps the higher pixel density ?

Comment: Yeah as it's relatively small. And For the human Eye Probably Indistinguishable.